# POSTtoTwitter in offline Mode (without user's password)

Tags: api, post, twitter, tweets

i have authenticated user with Twiter .which return user detail's

But i want to posttoTwitter with just username or id in offline mode.

Can any help me in this :)

Comment: How can you post to Twitter while offline? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to post to Twitter with only their username.

From an API pserspective, it's not even possible to post to Twitter if you have their username AND their password.  API applications that want to communicate with Twitter need to use Twitter's implementation of OAuth.

A good starting point is the [Twitter OAuth FAQ](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554658/OAuth-FAQ).  Or, you could use a library that someone else has written to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: thank you , i have done by saving OAuth_token, OAuth_token_secret in my database.Later i will use it to post update even in offline mode (user not logged in)